# Bing Search API: Not returning relatedSearches reliably

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When we search for "barack obama", "bill gates", "africa" and other various search terms in our app or on the [bing search api web demo](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-web-search-api), the api only returns relatedSearches about 10-20% of the time.  Most of the time its empty.  Strangely, searching for the queries listed on the web demo like "burrito recipes" and "new movies" returns relatedSearches 100% of the time.

Any ideas whats up?  I tweeted @AzureSupport and they acknowledge this may be a proper on microsofts side?  Would love any help as our app heavily relies on related search results.

Comment: Fwiw, we also see the same missing relatedSearches problem on the [API testing console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console
) with our api key as well